# How to Sync Sqlite data to sql server using Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi from so many days im searching about this topic but unable to get a hint also. if any one know how to sync sqlite data to sql server using  cordova and javascript please help out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Open source implementations**

There are some open source projects for syncing the PhoneGap app with the remote server. But you will have to adjust/implement to fit your project.

[Synchronize a local WebSQL Db to a server](https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync)

[Couchbase Lite PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin)

[Pouchdb](https://keyholesoftware.com/2014/11/03/pouchdb-for-offline/)

**Alternativly, custom API**

You could create your own set of API methods to send / update data from the `WebSQL` to your remote server `DB`. Flagging records that need to 'sync' to the external server. But you'll have to take measurements for a large bit of logics if the sync process is 2 way (central server - app - central server).

Since your question limits the amount of information it's hard to help out with more detailed information in this stage.